# Quickly move to top of next column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

For a particular task I want to set values for each column in a small set of rows.

I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> each time I enter a value. When I get to row 4, I'd like the next <kbd>Enter</kbd> to take me to row 2 of the next column:

[image: Return to top of next column]

I assume the solution will be to lock all cells other than the particular range I'm interested in. But [this documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a) gets pretty complicated to do with users' rights etc.

Is there a simple way to restrict editing to a range of cells without worrying about user-level security?

*Note: no wacky VBA solutions please.*

Answer (score 1):

**Important:** *First select your range.* (In your example: `A2:C4`)

Then:

use *only these keys and shortcuts* (without / after entering / editing a cell):

<kbd>Enter</kbd>               - move **down** (at the last row of your selection to the **first cell in the next column**)
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>    - similarly but in the **opposite direction**

---

<kbd>Tab</kbd>                 - move **right** (at the last column to the **first cell in the next row**)
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>      - similarly but in the **opposite direction**

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>     - stay in the current cell

*Don't use any other keys*, (particularly *not* the arrow keys) or you will *unselect your range!*
(It requires some practice.)

Comment: Wow, this is genuinely a new discovery for me. Very useful. That said, I'm going to stick with [this method](https://superuser.com/a/1208516/315715) since it's a little more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat counter-intuitively, the solution to this has nothing to do with the Changes ribbon group:

[image: Changes ribbon group]

In fact, the work is done in the `Format Cells...` dialog, available by selecting a range and right-clicking.

Then, in the Protection tab, untick the `Locked` checkbox:

[image: Protection tab]

Now when the sheet is protected, the unlocked cells will still be accessible.

Comment: On top of that, if the sheet is protected with "Select locked cells" unchecked and "Select unlocked cells" checked, cursor will jump around on hitting Enter as you wish it does.